# Serializing / deserializing optionals with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I need Morphia to support serialization of java 8 `Optional`. Morphia clearly doesn't special case `Optional`, and, by default, Morphia seems to serialize an `Optional` with a value to `{value: BLAH}` and to drop an empty `Optional` (as I have `dropEmpty` or whatever configured).

When I attempt to rehydrate an `Optional` containing an `enum` though, Morphia fails with a class cast exception in the bowels of the mapping logic:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:160)
```

Indeed, Morphia seems to be losing type information; when I implemented my own `TypeConverter`, the `MappedField` contained no `subClass` information, which is where I'd normally look for information for the information. Instead, I had to store class information about the inner value in a separate field so that the result ends up looking like:
`{"valueClassName" : "full.class.name" "value" : BLAH}`.

Is there a more elegant way of handling this? This pretty much seems like a special case of `IterableConverter` (although that clearly depends on the `subClass` value being present within `MappedField` as well.

For what it's worth, 'upgrading morphia' isn't much of an option, because of the myriad bugs that erupt whenever we try to do so. This was failing with org.mongodb.morphia version 0.108

Comment: What about Morphia 1.1.1 is "erupting" on you?  For what it's worth, I'm working on a set of Java 8 specific Converters that should be available with 1.2.0.

Comment: @evanchooly: well, we haven't tried to upgrade very recently (not to 1.1.1 either), but an example exception that we experienced: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014115/morphia-mappingexception-a-type-could-not-be-found-for-field-null-null. I think you and I actually discussed it in a different medium. I'd like to upgrade but it's hard to find the time -- is it your opinion that 1.1.1 would be a more successful upgrade than 1.0.1 was?

Comment: This [test](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/41a4fdc17af36822a6be9c9169c669d5043d128e/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/mapping/EmbeddedMappingTest.java#L39-L39) shows your other scenario working.  You should upgrade and see if your problem persists.  (No pun intended.)